# loading standard qt plugins MANUALLY and dynamically

Tags: qt, jpeg

Can anyone please give an example of HOW TO LOAD qjpeg or any other standard QT plugin manually. Please give a CODE EXAMPLE, Not a link to qt pages because I already know the following facts:

1. I am not linking qt as static lib.
2. I know how to deploy standard qt plugins (this is the automatic part)
   2.1. for qjpeg you copy qjpeg4.dll to ./imageformats/qjpeg4.dll as . being the base dir
       of your app.
   but I want to load and use qjpeg lib.

as in

```
QPluginLoader loader("qjpeg4.dll");
if (loader.instance()) {
    cout << "ok" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "fail" << endl << loader.errorString().toStdString() << endl;
}


QList<QByteArray> list = QImageReader::supportedImageFormats();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    f << list.at(i).constData() << std::endl;
}
```

this does not print jpg and jpg images cannot be read and written. Maybe if someone adds something more here it will work. or maybe I am copletely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this but here is an educated guess, you are probably doing the right thing to load the plugin but by not going the normal route the `QImageReader` does not actually know about the plugin being available. If you really need to explicitely load you plugin, you can probably cast the result of `QPlugiLoader::instance()` to a `QImageIOPlugin` and using the `QIOImageHandler` to read your jpgs, but it looks like you would have to forgo using the `QImageReader`